# How to find the 3 furthest points from each other in array of Vector3 points?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a "triangle" shape using the 3 furthest vector3 points in a LineRenderer.positions. I do have an origin point which is going to be one of the furthest points, so technically I only need to find 2 more points.

Not sure what the formula would be for this?

Answer (score 0):

Since as you say you already know one of the points you could simply do e.g.

```
using System.Linq;

...

Vector3 yourKnownOrigin;
var points = lineRenderer.GetPositions();

var furthestPoints = points
    // orders the points by distance the furthest being first 
    .OrderByDescending(p => (p - yourKnownOrigin).sqrMagnitude)
    // take the first two items -> two furthest points 
    .Take(2)
    .ToList();

// If there are not enough points in the line you might want to check this case here

var a = furthestPoints[0];
var b = furthestPoints[1];
```

Or if you're not a fan of Linq

```
Vector3 yourKnownOrigin;
var points = lineRenderer.GetPositions();

var a = yourKnownOrigin;
var b = yourKnownOrigin ;
var float distA = Marhf.Infinity;
var float distB = Mathf.Infinity;

foreach(var p in points)
{
    var dist = (p - yourKnownOrigin).sqrMagnitude;

    if(dist < distA)
    {
        b = a;
        distB = distA;

        distA = dist;
        a = p;
    }
    else if(dist < distB)
    {
        distB = dist;
        b = p;
    }
}
```

Note that for comparing distances the `sqrMagnitude` is more efficient than using `Distance` since the latter has to additionally take the square root.